# How can I create a Connection to Postgres using Typeorm

Tags: postgresql, typescript, graphql, typeorm

I am following a YouTube video series from Ben Awad published 1/2019 titled TypeGraphQL. The first video establishes the development environment and the second introduces Typeorm and PostgreSQL. At this point in the videos things are quite simple. The code defines a single Entity and creates a connection which should cause the code to create the table on startup.
I get this error on startup:

```
[nodemon] to restart at any time, enter `rs`
[nodemon] watching path(s): *.*
[nodemon] watching extensions: ts,json
[nodemon] starting `ts-node src/index.ts`

/Users/jboss/projects/ts-graphql/src/index.ts:141
export {EntityManager} from "./entity-manager/EntityManager";
        ^
TypeError: Cannot set property EntityManager of #<Object> which has only a getter
    at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/jboss/projects/ts-graphql/src/index.ts:141:9)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1063:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1103:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:914:32)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:822:14)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:956:19)
    at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:74:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/jboss/projects/ts-graphql/src/index.ts:5:1)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1063:30)
    at Module.m._compile (/Users/jboss/projects/ts-graphql/node_modules/ts-node/src/index.ts:858:23)
[nodemon] app crashed - waiting for file changes before starting...
```

Here is tsconfig.json

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es6",
    "module": "commonjs",
    "lib": ["dom", "es6", "es2017", "esnext.asynciterable"],
    "sourceMap": true,
    "outDir": "./dist",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "declaration": false,

    "composite": false,
    "removeComments": true,
    "noImplicitAny": true,
    "strictNullChecks": true,
    "strictFunctionTypes": true,
    "noImplicitThis": true,
    "noUnusedLocals": true,
    "noUnusedParameters": true,
    "noImplicitReturns": true,
    "noFallthroughCasesInSwitch": true,
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": false,
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "baseUrl": ".",
    "rootDir": "src"
  },
  "exclude": ["node_modules"],
  "include": ["./src/**/*.tsx", "./src/**/*.ts"]
}
```

Here is package.json:

```
{
  "name": "ts-graphql",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "main": "index.js",
  "license": "MIT",
  "dependencies": {
    "apollo-server-express": "^2.13.1",
    "bcryptjs": "^2.4.3",
    "express": "^4.17.1",
    "graphql": "^15.0.0",
    "pg": "^8.1.0",
    "reflect-metadata": "^0.1.13",
    "type-graphql": "^1.0.0-rc.1",
    "typeorm": "^0.2.24"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/bcryptjs": "^2.4.2",
    "@types/express": "^4.17.6",
    "@types/graphql": "^14.5.0",
    "@types/node": "^14.0.1",
    "nodemon": "^2.0.3",
    "ts-node": "^8.10.1",
    "typescript": "^3.9.2"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "nodemon --exec ts-node src/index.ts"
  }
}
```

Here is ormconfig.json:

```
{
  "name": "default",
  "type": "postgres",
  "host": "localhost",
  "port": 5432,
  "username": "postgres",
  "password": "docker",
  "database": "typegraphql",
  "synchronize": true,
  "logging": true,
  "entities": [ 
    "src/entity/**/*.*"
  ]
}
```

And index.ts:

```
import { ApolloServer } from "apollo-server-express";
import * as Express from "express";
import { buildSchema, Resolver, Query } from 'type-graphql';
import { createConnection } from "typeorm";

@Resolver()
class HelloResolver {

  @Query(() => String, {name: 'helloWorld'})
  async hello() {
    return "Hi from Typescript GraphQL!";
  }
}

let main = async () => {
  await createConnection();

  const schema = await buildSchema({
    resolvers: [HelloResolver]
  });

  const apolloServer = new ApolloServer({ schema })

  const app = Express();
  apolloServer.applyMiddleware({ app });
  app.listen(4000, () => {
    console.log('Server started on http://localhost:4000');
  });
}

main();
```

Last is User.ts:

```
import {Entity, PrimaryGeneratedColumn, Column, BaseEntity} from "typeorm";

@Entity( { schema: "public" })
export class User extends BaseEntity {

    @PrimaryGeneratedColumn()
    id: number;

    @Column()
    firstName: string;

    @Column()
    lastName: string;

    @Column("text", { unique: true})
    email: string;

    @Column()
    password: string;

}
```

Can anyone tell me how to get this to work? I don’t think I understand the issue.

Answer (score 0):

This was reported on the Typeorm project yesterday as a bug. Took me a day to find it. Found it in their Slack. Love Slack.
https://github.com/typeorm/typeorm/issues/6054
The solution for me was to do:

```
npm install tslib@1.11.2
```

And then to add the following to package.json:

```
  "resolutions": {
    "ts.lib": "1.11.2"
  },
```

Then to re-start with yarn.

Seems as though tslib 1.12 is causing a few problems.